# Silverlight torrent client

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

Is it possible to implement a torrent client using Silverlight? If not, is it possible to do that in Silverlight OOB?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with trusted OOB app.

Comment: any online samples you know of?